# Collision trigger always seems to be colliding

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

All I can find through research is objects NOT colliding... My problem is it is ALWAYS colliding... I have messed this code up all over trying to make it recognize that it is not colliding. They are not touching anything at all in unity ( cube triggers using box colliders )... I am kind of new to unity and I feel like I am over looking something simple?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Battlecam : MonoBehaviour 
{

//calling speed integers
    public float upSpeed = 10;
    public float rightSpeed = 60;
//bool colliding
    public bool colliding = false;


//triggers
    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        colliding = true;
    }


    void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        colliding = false;
    }


    void Start()
    {
            colliding = false;
    }
//camera movements
    void Update()
        {
            if (colliding = false) {
                float horizontal = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal") * rightSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.Translate (0, horizontal, 0);

                float vertical = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") * upSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
                transform.Translate (0, 0, vertical);

                colliding = false;
            } 
            else
                colliding = true;
        }

}
```

I can't figure out what is throwing my bool to true. I have scoured google and stack exchange for any answer, with little luck. Thanks

Comment: You might want to use `OnTriggerStay(Collider other)`. I can't think of a disadvantage of using it right now. It would probably be the same as `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` though.

Comment: Is it possible for you to show us an image of your scene?

Comment: @Bobthezealot I don't think  `OnTriggerStay(Collider other)` has to do anything

Comment: OK, I didn't think it would do anything either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a bug in this line:

```
 if (colliding = false) {
```

Which should be,

```
 if (colliding == false) // or if(!colliding)
```

Comment: Ah, I knew it was something easy. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Dinal24 had the first point.

The other thing you should fix is:
Change `OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)` to `OnTriggerStay(Collider other)`.
Why?
If the program starts when the the object is already touching(bool should return true), it is forced to return false because of:

```
void Start()
{
    colliding = false;
}
```

One option is, if you use `OnTriggerStay`, it will contantly detect if it's true or not.
Another option is to delete the `void Start()` completely. I don't think there is any need for it.

Comment: I was just trying to make it more memory efficient. That's my whole goal. So OnTriggerStay is probably a no go. And since it is in the start, I wanted to define it on the start, but now that I look at it, it is already defined above, wouldn't it be more beneficial to take colliding = false out of the start? This code is going to get prettttyyy lengthy and consume some memory, so I am trying to keep it short and efficient. +1 by the way, very valid point